# vue-router.d.ts(734, 5): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'MyType'

Tags: typescript, vue-router

I can use `m` in the first and second levels, but an error is prompted after the third level

this error is about `RouteRecordRaw`，because, replace with a custom type will not appear

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRsmX.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js3ko.jpg)

code:

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "bug-demo-type",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';

type MyType = RouteRecordRaw & {
  m?: string;
  children?: Array<MyType>;
};

const ddd: Array<MyType> = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirect: '',
    children: [
      {
        m: '',
        path: '',
        redirect: '',
        children: [
          {
            m: '',
            path: '',
            redirect: '',
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                redirect: '',
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```